# How to mock model with errors using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, view, rspec2

I'm testing view layer of my Rails app.

This view is for Customer model, where I'm calling errors for it, like so (haml):

```
- if @customer.errors.present?
  - flash[:warn] = ""
- @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
  - flash[:warn] += msg + "<br />"

= form_for :customer, :url => customer_registration_path do |f|
  - validated = resource.errors.any?
  .field{ :class => !validated ?  "" : (resource.errors.has_key?(:email) ? "failed" : "passed" )  }
    = f.text_field "email",   :placeholder => "почта", :autocomplete => "off"
    .status
  .field{ :class => !validated ?  "" : (resource.errors.has_key?(:password) ? "failed" : "passed" ) }
    = f.password_field "password", :placeholder => "пароль", :autocomplete => "off"
    .status
  .field{ :class => !validated ?  "" : (resource.errors.has_key?(:password_confirmation) ? "failed" : "passed" ) }
    = f.password_field "password_confirmation", :placeholder => "повторите пароль", :autocomplete => "off"
    .status
  = f.submit "" # Зарегистрироваться
```

I need to test presence of, say, wrapper around "email" field, marked as "failed".

How to write mock for Customer model, emulating presence of corresponding errors ?

Comment: I think this is repeated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248335/how-to-mock-model-with-errors-using-rspec

Answer (score 0):

My practice is to make actual invalid objects, not really a fan of mocking.
But if you insist:

```
it "should render errors" do
  @user = User.new
  @user[:errors][:email] = 'invalid'
  @view.stub!(:resource).and_return { @user }
  render
  ......
end
```

Btw, I think most of the functionality that you build is offered by dynamic form: https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form